# Multiple Input fields with same id

Tags: php, jquery

I am rendering data from php code with a input field but when i retrieve data from database the input field is replicated and i have assigned one id and one class value to it now i am facing that if i use id it only show me the 1st value only.if i use class it start iterating it and complete till each field and show empty where input fields are empty

Jquery Code is this

```
$('.submit-button').on('click',function(){
    $('.datecontrol').each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
});
```

and my whole html is provided [here](http://pastie.org/4746295)

Comment: What do you wanna do? There can be only one ID per element.

Comment: You should never assign a static ID in a loop - the whole idea behind IDs is that they're unique. Add a counter variable in your loop and append that to your ID, or use one of the retrieved DB values. Does the datepicker not work if you call it on the class rather than the ID?

Comment: the datepicker is working fine with class but  the main issue is that i could not generate the value selected from the calender in 2nd or 3rd textfield

Comment: @Andreas i have provided the whole file in my question u can check it plz !!

Comment: @fahad do you want to get the values in .datecontrol fields??

Answer (score 0):

First, as per the title, it is not a good idea to use multiple fields with same id. It will create problems is CSS, Scripting, etc.

Next, if selecting certain numbers of field only is your problem, then assign a different class to the fields to represent a particular group.

Comment: Well @Starx plz check this link and then u vl understand y i used same class http://pastie.org/4746295

Comment: @fahad, I am sorry, I am not free ATM to go through your codes, but what I meant is, you can assign additional classes to separate groups.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your Question but I think the answer you are searching for - or what you should think about is following:

In JQuery you can select an ID with the class example eg.

```
$("#yourid.yourclass");
```

This means you can keep an unique ID (which is important for the workflow) and you can still assign groups with the classes!

so an example element would look like this

```
<div id="mynumber" class="red"></div>
<script>
$("#mynumber.red").on("click", function()
{
alert('I was clicked');
});</script>
```

And for looking up empty items you can use .length()

As an additional Information: To validate your document while using identical ids don't use the html tag id="" but instead data-id="" as data- elements will be valid anyways.

Comment: do not use .live because it is deprecated, .on() is the new method you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

your code has some syntax errors, so if you want to show only fields with values

```
    $('.submit-button').on('click',function(){
       $('.datecontrol').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()!='') // check if field is empty
           alert($(this).val());
       }); //-->missing closing brackets
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not use same id for multiple elements, if you want jquery code to find elements, it will only find the last one.

Better, you use class, or you can use title tag to use multiple elements using `.each()`.